# Why should I mark the last column of class model as optional when importing a CSV file with FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I read many questions here on StackOverflow trying to find a solution to a simple problem. I'm importing a CSV file using FileHelpers library. The CSV file has no delimiter at the last column, and when I try to import I get the error

```
Line: 2 Column: 179. Delimiter ',' not found after field 'Active' (the record has less fields, the delimiter is wrong or the next field must be marked as optional)
```

It's right, because my file looks like

```
...,Clip Ons,,D02,8 Card Wallet,Y
...,D02,Bathurst Chain Crossbody,Y
```

One solution I found is to mark the last column using attribule `FieldOptional`. The problem is that the column isn't optional; it must throw an error if the last column is null.

How can I handle this situation avoiding '`FieldOptional`' attribute?

Comment: Its sounding like the CSV had more records than you expected....

Comment: The two lines that you show of your csv are not the same!  The first line has 6 fields and the second only 4.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway this is just an example to show that I got no delimiter at the end of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version are you using? With FileHelpers 3.1.5, this works fine:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class MySpec
{
    public string Column1;
    public string Column2;
    public string Column3;
    public string Column4;
    public string Column5;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileHelpersEngine = new FileHelperEngine<MySpec>();
        var records = fileHelpersEngine.ReadString("Clip Ons,,D02,8 Card Wallet,Y");
        var firstRecord = records.First();
        Assert.AreEqual("Clip Ons", firstRecord.Column1);
        Assert.AreEqual(string.Empty, firstRecord.Column2);
        Assert.AreEqual("D02", firstRecord.Column3);
        Assert.AreEqual("8 Card Wallet", firstRecord.Column4);
        Assert.AreEqual("Y", firstRecord.Column5);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

With older versions (2.0 if I remember correctly), you needed to add one more extra (dummy) property and mark it `[FieldOptional]`.  This means: *the last delimiter is optional and I don't care about any contents after the last delimiter*.

So your class would then look like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class MySpec
{
    public string Column1;
    public string Column2;
    public string Column3;
    public string Column4;
    public string Column5;
    [FieldOptional]
    public string Dummy;
}
```

This class also works with the above example.

Comment: I've got version 2.9.9. I actually tried to implement your second solution, but I was still getting the error

Comment: I tested it and it works. The problem by my side is that we use a dynamic engine based on a table on the db, but I thought that this issue wasn't related to the fact that we build up the FileHelpersEngine dynamically.

Comment: You can still add an extra `FieldOptional` dynamically if you need. `field = classBuilder.AddField("Dummy", typeof(string));` and then `field.FieldOptional = true;`